# Qemu Backing Files Question

Tags: files, nfs, rm, qemu

If I'm creating a new.qcow2 qcow2 image based on a backing file (called base.qcow2) and the backing file is located on an nfs share. What happens if someone tries to modify, replace, or delete the base.qcow2?

Is there a locking mechanism that prevents this?
Will all of the blocks be copied to the new.qcow2 image prior to removing or modifying the base.qcow2?

The scenario is as follows:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 -b /mnt/nfs/base.qcow2 /localdisk/new.qcow2
```

On the nfs server or other client:

```
rm nfs/base.qcow2
```

What happens to new.qcow2 created from base.qcow2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens if someone tries to modify, replace, or delete the
>   base.qcow2?

The images based on the base image become irrelevant/corrupted/useless. Full clones will keep working of course.

> Is there a locking mechanism that prevents this?

Built into qemu - no. Management systems like oVirt/RHEV will have those in place.

> Will all of the blocks be copied to the new.qcow2 image prior to
>   removing or modifying the base.qcow2?

Only if you manually do a `qemu-img rebase`. If you simply edit the base file, or use it directly with a VM instead of the last derived image in a snapshot chain, you'll break the entire snapshot tree.

As for the actual scenario, the `-b` option will create only a delta image, containing only the differences between the new snapshot and the base image. If you delete the base, the snapshot becomes useless since it has no reference. Go over http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Virtualization_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Tips_and_tricks-Using_qemu_img.html for better reference.

Comment: Perfect explanation, I guess i'll then create pure clones because I have no method of ensuring that someone else may not change the base image. How does RHEV and oVirt implement this locking mechanism?

Comment: First, if you clone, you can stick to `virsh clone` but if you prefer to work with the image, you want to use `qemu-img convert` with the output format the same is input format if you don't want to change it. qemu-img will preserve the metadata better than cp or dd. As for RHEV/oVirt, the system manages the images, you don't even need to know about them, so it prevents you from touching them. If you use block storage (FC, iSCSI, etc), the LVs holding the backing image will be mounted r/o